# When do relationships in ERD diagrams get a separate table in a RDBMS

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Title is the question.  When should a relationship in an ER diagram be given its own table in a RDBMS?  For instance, one mail courier(with attributes eid and surname) can deliver a number of packages but a package(attributes,pid, sent_By, going_to) can only have one mail courier.  Would it make sense to make a table for the relationship called delivers(with an attribute of the time that the package was delivered)? or should the eid of the mail_courier and time_delivered from the deliver relationship be added to the package entity? Also, what would be an example when you would not want to add the attributes to the package entity?

Comment: No need for the `mysql` tag. This applies to any relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying is to create a [one-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between two entities. And for that, there is no need to create a separate table; as you mentioned in your question, just add those two attributes to the package table.

Where you would need to create a separate table is when you want to achieve [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between two entities. For example, take twitter's followers. One user can have many followers and a follower can follow many users. You can't do that the *relational* way without creating a new table with just those two columns.

Comment: Good answer. Another classic example of Many-to-Many is Books & Authors. A book may be have one or more authors co-writing. An author may write more than one book in her career. Such a relationship mandates a third table, a bridge table, between them. Perhaps named “Authorship”. This child table has two parents, one being the “Book” table, the other being the “Author” table. Authorship has a foreign key linking to Book, and another foreign key linking to Author.